# How to create separate dataframe by looping over specific column indexes and using a conditional or statement in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Currently, I have a datatable that I want to separate into two separate dataframes in R. In order to do this, I want to loop through a certain number of columns and use an or statement.

Ex:

```
>my_data<-fread("...csv")
>my_data
DOGS   CATS   PENGUINS   TURTLES   LIONS   TIGERS
3      0      0          0         1       8
0      5      2          4         0       1
0      0      0          7         0       0
```

So for example, if I want to make a new datatable that includes the rows where either the values in column 2, 3, 4 or 6 are 0, how I would I do that?

Currently I'm doing

```
my_animals<-my_data[CATS==0 | PENGUINS==0 | TURTLES==0 | TIGERS ==0]
>my_animals
DOGS   CATS   PENGUINS   TURTLES   LIONS   TIGERS
3      0      0          0         1       8
0      0      0          7         0       0
```

which is the datatable I want but my code is not efficient, and I want to add more conditions later (i.e. if I have a new column and I want to add FROGS==0)
Ideally, I'd want to use the column indexes (so I could use 2:4 somehow instead of typing CATS, PENGUINS, TURTLES), but is there any way to shorten my code and use column indexes instead of column names?

Comment: with `fread` and your method of row subsetting, you should mention that this is a `data.table`.

Comment: ahh... nice catch @lmo...and here I prepared a df solution..

Comment: @Sotos. you could always post it with a step converting the object to a data.frame.

Comment: @lmo right! thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method using data.table is to use `rowSums`:

```
my_animals <- my_data[rowSums(my_data[, .SD, 
                      .SDcols=c("CATS", "PENGUINS", "TURTLES", "TIGERS")] == 0) > 1, ]
```

This returns the desired result

```
my_animals
   DOGS CATS PENGUINS TURTLES LIONS TIGERS
1:    3    0        0       0     1      8
2:    0    0        0       7     0      0
```

The code can be interpreted as follows:

- `my_data[, .SD, .SDcols=c("CATS", "PENGUINS", "TURTLES", "TIGERS")]` subsets the data.table, selecting the desired columns.
- `rowSums(...] == 0)` sums the elements in the data.table that are equal to 0 for each row
- `rowSums(...] == 0) > 0`returns a logical vector where any row with at least one 0 corresponds to TRUE.
- `my_data[rowSums(...]` subsets my_data on the logical vector.

As @Sotos mentions, it is possible to use the column indices rather than their names in `.SDcols`, so something like:

```
my_data[rowSums(my_data[, .SD, .SDcols=c(2:4, 6)] == 0) > 1, ]
```

returns the equivalent object.

Comment: you could also use the indexes at `.SDcols = c(2:4, 6)` or does that violate the 0r cond?

Comment: I was just thinking about that. :)

Comment: If I wanted to get the rows where instead of 0, I wanted 1, would I just replace ==0 with ==1? What does the > 1 do?

Comment: Yes replacing `==0` with `== 1` will tell `rowSums` to count the elements equal to (within numerical precision) 1. See the addition in my answer for more info on `> 0`.

Answer (score 2):

If we convert your `data.table` to `data.frame` then,

```
df <- as.data.frame(my_data)
ind <- which(colSums(apply(df[c(2:4, 6)], 1, function(i) i == 0)) != 0)
df[ind,]
#  DOGS CATS PENGUINS TURTLES LIONS TIGERS
#1    3    0        0       0     1      8
#3    0    0        0       7     0      0
```